# In XML Web Services, what is the best practice for passing exceptions back to the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, exception

If my web method throws an exception, what is the best practice for passing that exception to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In plain old asmx services by catching this exception and rethrowing a [`SoapException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx) and filling the [Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.detail(VS.90).aspx) property.
- In WCF by throwing a [`FaultException<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx). As far as the *catching* is concerned a good place to do this is a custom [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) that would provide the appropriate fault to the client.

Comment: So, something like this?

catch(Exception)
{
throw new SoapException();
}

Comment: If you throw an exception from an asmx web service method, what ever the exception is gets turned into a SoapException. If you want to pass back more info than the SoapException already does, you need to explicitly create your own SoapException and set the Details property as Darin mentioned, then through that. If you don't want to pass back anything special, then you don't need to create a new SoapException yourself. It will happen automatically. Check the SoapException documentation.